# Save tables in Docker container

Tags: java, mysql, docker, database-administration

I need some advice for best practice, maybe. I need start web application with web server and database. How to link web server to database I found out. But I have some problem with DB.

If I wanna save my tables after server down (server where containers start). As I know all information of container reset after delete. Also I know about verbose folders(`-v` flag) but I don't know where `MySQL` save it's tables and other information and don't know is it good idea.

So, could someone tell me how to correctly save my created tables in container?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this tutorial:

https://github.com/tutumcloud/tutum-docker-mysql

Basically, you have MySQL on your machine and then, on `/var/lib/mysql` , you can start the container:

`docker run -d -p 3306:3306 -v /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql tutum/mysql`

In this case, I'm using `tutum/mysql` image. You would be mounting the database file volume from your host to your container. When the container goes down, you still will have the data on your machine.